# Is it normal to irssi freezes when receiving dcc?

Tags: ssh, performance, screen, irc

I'm running it over `screen` with Raspberry Pi Model B, but when a streaming begins, I am unable to type anything, even <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd> doesn't work, but changing `screen`'s window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>#</kbd> works, so, it's not the hardware who freezes, it is only `irssi`, I wonder if it have only one thread or what. When the streaming ends it starts responding again, with all previous commands typed at once.

I wonder if there is some tips to prevent `irssi` to freezes that way, otherwise I'll be very bored by waiting all streamings unable to talk.

Comment: Not an answer but posting to say I get this also running Debian Linux 3.4.104 sun-xi on a Cubietruck. It's certainly a real thing but I think I never experienced it when I used my x86 system as my server. So possibly this is linked to the computers being ARM?

Comment: You may be right, I opened a [bug issue](https://github.com/irssi/irssi/issues/159) but so far they hadn't answered.